# Segmentation fault in small text processing program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a c++ function `read_inputdata` to read some inputfile and write the values to a an array. I first declare an array of appropriate length, and with the function I fill it with the values in the inputfile.

But I get a segmentation fault. Anybody an idea what I did wrong?

```
#define MAX 140160
void read_inputdata(double input[MAX], char files[40]);

char inputfiles1[40] = "input/Hesse04/FR_Hes_rad.txt";
std::cout << "Declaring the arrays" << std::endl;
double input1[MAX];
std::cout << "Calling function read_inputdata" << std::endl;
read_inputdata(input1, inputfiles1);
```

When I compile and run this I get:

```
Declaring the arrays
Calling function read_inputdata
Segmentation fault
```

So at the moment he calls the function `read_inputdata` something goes wrong, because he doesn't reach `std::cout << "In function read_inputdata" << std::endl;`.

The function:

```
void read_inputdata(double input[MAX], char files[40])
{
    std::cout << "In function read_inputdata" << std::endl;
    std::ifstream inputfile;
    inputfile.open(files);
    if (inputfile.is_open())
    {
        char temp[100];
        double getal[2][MAX];
        int i = 0;
        while(!inputfile.getline(temp, 100).eof())
        {
            char delims[] = "\t ,";
            char *result = NULL;
            result = strtok( temp, delims );
            int j=0;
            while( result != NULL )
            {
                getal[j][i]=atof(result);
                result = strtok( NULL, delims );
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        inputfile.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            input[i] = getal[1][i];
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "WARNING: unable to open file" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you're not dynamically allocating the array? That's a fairly large size.

Comment: This `double getal[2][MAX]; ` declares an array that is several megabytes in size. Are you sure you have that much stack space on your system?

Comment: yes, indeed, when I tried with a smaller `#define MAX 140160` it worked, so it has probably to do with the available space. Why I didn't allocate it dynamically? I tried, but it gave also some fault, and I am not a real experienced programmer in C++, so I gave it up. But I will try with the answer below.

Comment: For debug output, you should use std::cerr instead of std::cout.
std::cout writes to STDOUT and is buffered, so the last message you see in your terminal is not necessarily the last that was written by your program.
std::cerr, on the contrary, writes to STDERR and is not buffered.

Comment: @Bo Persson: how can you know how much stack space you have? And can you change that?

Comment: Depends on compiler. Check your compiler options.

Comment: @Frank (myself) Just looked it up: std::endl flushes the output stream, so you will indeed see the last output. Nevertheless, I'd still recommend using std::cerr for debug messages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably running out of stack. Please use pointers, dynamic allocations and even better, [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

```
#define MAX 140160
void read_inputdata(double *input, char *files);

char inputfiles1[40] = "input/Hesse04/FR_Hes_rad.txt";
std::cout << "Declaring the arrays" << std::endl;
double *input1 = new double[MAX];
std::cout << "Calling function read_inputdata" << std::endl;
read_inputdata(input1, inputfiles1);
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that j is exceeding the permissible range of 0..1. Try this:

```
        #include <assert.h>

        ...

        int j=0;
        while( result != NULL )
        {
            assert(j < 2); // make sure that we don't try to write beyond the bounds of getal !
            getal[j][i]=atof(result);
            result = strtok( NULL, delims );
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: Using assert for error checking is bad! It should only be for circumstances where your application is well screwed; not logical errors. I guess it might be OK if this is used for an initial logic test and removed after...

Comment: @Daniel: what you say is correct, but I suggested this merely as an initial debugging step and also perhaps to introduce the idea to the OP that adding asserts is a useful and important part of programming